# Как проверить играет ли музыка в mediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пробовал использовать этот код, но ничего не заработало. Может есть еще способы, как проверить играет ли музыка?

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(potok[posit]);
                  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                  mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                  mediaPlayer.start();
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам вот этот код надо вызвать в коллбеке лиснера `onPreparedListener`
Ответ, почему так - вы асинхронно готовите плеер к проигрыванию, и весь код ниже вызывается синхронно, т.е. раньше, чем отработает коллбек

```
@Override    
void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую